# Suppressing asdf:load-system console output

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I have created a small project using Steel Bank Common Lisp and I am using ASDF to compile and load it. The load command is:

```
(asdf:load-system :<my-system>)
```

Everything works fine (the program gets compiled and runs fine) but I keep getting output like

```
; compiling file "[...].lisp" (written 13 APR 2014 06:20:03 PM):
; compiling (DEFPACKAGE :<my-package> ...)
; compiling (DEFUN <my-func-1> ...)
; compiling (DEFUN <my-func-2> ...)
; compiling (DEFUN <my-func-3> ...)
```

each time the program is recompiled.

I suppose this output comes from `asdf` because I am invoking the application with

```
sbcl --noinform --noprint --script runner_sbcl.lisp
```

where `runner_sbcl.lisp` loads the actual application via `asdf:load-system`. So I suppose
this output does not come from `sbcl`.

Is there any way to disable console output in `asdf:load-system`? I would like to be only notified about compilation errors / warnings.
I could not find any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about

```
(setf *load-verbose* nil)
(setf *load-print* nil)
(setf *compile-verbose* nil)
(setf *compile-print* nil)
```

?

Why are they set, anyway?

Comment: Do you mean `(setf *load-verbose* nil)`, etc? I think the `*` have been interpreted as *italics* formatting in your answer. Anyway, I tried this out and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround for a similar issue I had with quicklisp's ql:quickload.

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  ;; asdf:load-system or ql:quickload..
  (asdf:load-system :<your-system>))
```

Comment: That might cons up a rather large string.  It should be better to bind `*standard-output*` to a stream that goes to nirvana (sort of like `/dev/null`).  You can create such a stream with `make-broadcast-stream` without arguments.

Comment: Didn't know about `make-broadcast-stream`.  That sounds very handy.  Thanks!